# A6211 LED driver Radio interference

Tags: led, led-driver, emi-filtering

I am working on a small side hobby project where I am using a A6211 LED driver,
But the LED driver is causing quite a lot of interference on a radio, I tried using shielded cables, add ferrite cores, but it all doesn't seem to help.

My schematic:

[image]

I tried changing the filter capacitor according the datasheet (C5), to different values, it all doesn't seem to help much.

[Video of the interference](https://www.kapwing.com/videos/64906042079d1200ad38866b)

I am definitely not a specialist, but EMI seems to be issue here, where to start to address this issue?

This is the board layout
[image: Board layout]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add a photo of the circuit including wires to the LEDs, with the radio out of the way. More specifics on what you tried shielding, filtering and grounding. Also results of positioning the radio: distance and orientation.

Comment: Radio distance doesn't seem to affect much, also orientation.
The leds are mounted on a pcb, where two simple wires are attached to the pcb via a screw terminal.

Comment: Are the “two simple wires” connecting the LEDs to the driver? How long are they? Did you try twisted pair, with or without a shield? Grounding?

Comment: Aprox 5cm, I haven't tried shielding those.

Comment: What does your PCB layout look like?

Comment: Nothing too [Complex](https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/06/19/ZaBZQ.jpg/).I would say, I've added a ground plane in the layout. Don't mind the 2 leds on the side . component in the center is the driver

Comment: AM radios are designed to pickup interference. Use a good FM radio instead.

Comment: @Audioguru that will only mask the interference not solve it 

Comment: That's an airband AM transceiver tuned to 122.3 MHz, right? (For posterity, that's a frequency used for voice communications between aircraft and/or air traffic control.) It would probably be worth mentioning that in the question, since I was assuming from the comments that you were concerned about interference on the medium-wave AM broadcast band.

Comment: Try soldering decoupling capacitors (100 nF ceramic) with as short leads as possible across the input Vcc and ground. Preferably in parallel to C5 and your LED+ rail to ground too.

Comment: @winny would it be possible to push me a drawing of the changed schematic ? , also the datasheet is speaking of a filtering capacitor (c5) to filter out noise . What value would be a good starting point ? They mention it would be possible to calculate that but I am having some issues with that

Comment: Too late today, but follow C2 all the way to the IC, the Vin pin and the GND pin, solder a capacitor, either though hole with leads cut down to as short as you can, or SMD if you can make it fit.

Comment: If you are worried about a particular VHF frequency you might try changing the resistor on the TON pin, that should change the basic switching frequency which might move the interference farther away from the frequencies that you're trying to receive.  Additional by-pass caps on the input side may also help, as well as using a metallic enclosure.

Comment: @Nedd I think this quite solves 90 percent of the issue , it’s remarkable less , together with a tighter ferrite coil it’s close to zero now